# SOLANA Rent and Rent Exemption | Which accounts they are taking rent from

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

Hi I'm new to SOLANA Blockchain , While gazing through the charges inside Solana, I found there is a fee associated with transaction like , minting tokens , transferring them , creating token accounts etc.. But there is another charge called Rent that is associated with an account as per the size of the instructions we are storing. But I'm confused that which account this rent is associated to.I'm using

1 **Payer Account** as payer in transactions , minting etc.. 
This **Payer Account** is also the owner of the spl-token that I created 
2 **Token account** that holds the tokens 
3 **Normal wallets** which are used for sending / receiving / minting tokens 
4 **Smart contracts** to execute more operations , \

So I have **4 accounts** as said above , so from which account solana will be taking the rent from,Please help ..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Hi, @Ouroborus If I can figure out that, I will pass that fee on my code to that particular account to make it rent-exempt.